# arroz y frijoles: sambumbo

Tags: etimología, méxico, comida

Cuando alguien mezcla arroz y frijoles, mi esposa llama el resultado *sambumbo*.  Emplea la palabra en otras situaciones también, cuando ciertos ingredientes han sido mezclados de una forma improvisada por la persona que va a comer.  No la usaría cuando alguien sigue una receta.  En fin, tiene una idea intuitiva del significado de la palabra, pero no es tan fácil definirla más formalmente.

Si es relevante, ella es del Estado de México pero la familia de su papá es de Guerrero, México.

Mis preguntas son las siguientes:

1. ¿Cómo debe escribirse?  Cuento 32 posiblidades.
2. ¿Existe una definición establecida por lexicógrafos?
3. ¿Cuál será su etimología?

Comment: Estoy viendo que en el _Diccionario de americanismos_ aparece _[sambumbia](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=sambumbia)_, que en México es el nombre de una bebida fermentada, aunque en otros países significa "comida o bebida mal preparada, de poca calidad". Esto podría encajar con la idea que das de "comida improvisada", aunque no tiene por qué. ¿Podría ser esta la palabra que está empleando? Incluso en otros países significa "mezcla confusa de elementos de diversa naturaleza", que encaja aún más.

Comment: Parece que en la República Dominicana existe la receta [sambumbo](http://acento.com.do/e/Recetas3/principal.html), que contiene _Arroz, habichuelas, maíz, cebolla, tomate, ají, berenjena, brócoli, ajo, pollo, huevo, atún, aceite y sal_ y cuya foto encaja bastante con la _mezcla confusa de elementos de diversa naturaleza_ que menciona @Charlie

Comment: ¡Ja! En la foto se ve bastante más fino (y más rico) que un plato cotidiano de arroz y frijoles, pero "collage de lo que hay" sí aplica.

Answer (score 2):

El plato al que Ud. se refiere es el **chambre de guandules**, el cual también se conoce por el nombre *zambumbo* (y en ciertos círculos *zambumbio*).  Es un plato criollo, y proviene del Caribe.  Los guandules (la forma preferida es gandules, sin la u) son un tipo de frijol, entre alubias y lentejas (Cajanus cajan [Bot]).  No se venden en México, y posiblemente por eso, en la familia de su esposa, sustituían otro tipo de frijol.  El plato se elabora con arroz, puerco salado, salchichas italianas, y con una mezcla de otros comestibles tales como camote, calabacita (auyama), yuca, yautía (mafafa) etc.  En cuanto a la etimología  *chambre* es de francés, y significa "criollo".  A lo mejor, *zambumbo* proviene de raices africanos y denota que el plato se asociaba con la comida de los mestizos, pero eso no es más que mi conjetura.  Espero le ayude.

Answer (score -1):

En el libro "El origen de la comida dominicana" de Juan Bautista Nina logro ver este pequeño fragmento en la vista preliminar de Google:

> Sambumbio sigue siendo entre nosotros una especie de mezcla de muchas cosas alimenticias, pero despreciables. Según Fernando Ortiz, en su "Nuevo Catauro de Cubanismos", la palabra Sambumbia" significa suciedad, porquería, en el lenguaje de Calabar en Africa...

Y en un [listado de africanismos](https://bayamonweb.azurewebsites.net/cai/africanismos/):

> Sambumbia – bebida o comida mal preparada y de aspecto desagradable, mescolanza repugnante.

Por lo visto, se refiere a distintos tipos de bebidas fermentadas y a preparados alimenticios en los que se mezclan ingredientes. La z con que se escribe en muchas ocasiones, me imagino que se debe a la similitud fónica con *zambo*, que se refiere a los mestizos americanos mezcla de colono europeo, indígena americano y negro.

Comment: Parece que esto no es....